# Ordering with ActiveRecord, pagination with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, kaminari

The following (from the index-action of my activities-controller) has no effect on the order in which the entries are displayed:

```
@activities = Activity.order("updated_at").page(params[:page])
```

The .page-part is for the Kaminari-gem that does the pagination.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you are right. may be kaminari or somewhere else incorrect .
please look over your Activity's default_scope.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, the default_scope in the Activity-model was the reason. I totally forgot about that.